# check whether my method returns a valid result or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a spec where i am getting an Account object like below when i call the all method.

> got: #"accountResource",
>   :createdAt=>"2014-08-12T09:50:02.031", :createdBy=>2,
>   :updatedAt=>"2014-08-12T09:50:02.135", :updatedBy=>2,
>   :accountid=>2547, :name=>"account1", :description=>"Something about
>   account1", :disabled=>false}, @dirty_attributes=#>]>

Below is my spec.

```
it "should get all accounts" do       
    acc = Account.all({auth: @token});
    expect(acc) to eq(what)
end
```

I need to check whether my method returns a valid result or not. What to expect here with my account?.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 it "should get all accounts" do       
     acc = Account.all({auth: @token});
     expect(acc) to be_an(Array)
     expect(acc.first.class) to eq(Account)
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your should not check if instance is equal to another object. You should check objects properties instead:

```
it "should get all accounts" do       
  acc = Account.all({auth: @token});
  expect(acc.name) to eq("account1")
  expect(acc.description) to eq("Something about account1")
end
```

.. and so on!

Comment: What if it returns multiple objects? in that case how would we check.

Comment: You can map over collection, return array and compare it to yours. For example: account_names = accounts.map(&:name); expect(account_names).to eq(["name1"], ["name2"])